# Azure Blob Storage - Define Automation Task in Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage

I have defined within the Azure Portal a scheduled task to delete blobs older than x days. Now I need to script this to Powershell, however I couldn't find any information about this.
At this moment, feb 2023, Azure Blob Storage Automation Tasks are in Preview mode as it can be seen in this picture.

[image: Azure Blob Storage Portal UI]

Does anybody know if defining Automation Tasks in Powershell is possible at this moment? Thanks!

Comment: Why not using Azure function?

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Blob Storage - Define Automation Task in Powershell

You can use Azure Automation Runbook for this action:

You can use below PowerShell code to delete the blobs 10 days older:

```
$a="Storage account name " 
$ak="ETxeSAVNp7NkvWAYwri6M7+AStOQtSZQ=="
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $a -StorageAccountKey $ak

Get-AzStorageBlob -Container "name of container" -Context $context | where {$_.LastModified -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-10)}
```

$ak is the storage account key

If you dont want to give container name you can use below code:

```
    $a="Storage account name " 
    $ak="ETxeSAVNp7NkvWAYwri6M7+AStOQtSZQ=="
    $context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $a -StorageAccountKey $ak
    $c=Get-AzStorageContainer  -Context $context     
        foreach($con in $c)    
        {    
      Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $con -Context $context | where {$_.LastModified -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-10) 
        }
```

You can also use the below command to only delete specific type of blob:

```
Get-AzStorageBlob -Container "name of conatiner" -Blob *.txt -Context $ctx | where {$_.LastModified -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-10)}
```

In place of txt you can use jpg, etc.

Here -10 means 10 days older (you can give your required number of days).

Now create a [automation account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-create-standalone-account?tabs=azureportal) and then create a [powershell run book](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/automation-tutorial-runbook-textual) in it.

You can paste the above code in powershell run book and then you can [schedule the runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/manage-runbooks#schedule-a-runbook-in-the-azure-portal).

By this way you can create an automation task of PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! At this moment feb 2023, the Azure Blob Storage Automation Tasks don't yet have Powershell API provided by MSFT so this is probably a good alternative. However, I need to use Automation Tasks and I was looking for a way in which you could define Automation Tasks from Powershell.